# How to resolve 'ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.'?

Tags: image, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am making an SVM classifier to classify images. Google collab is used in this program and the files are uploaded in the Google Drive. The shape of the image is `torch.Size([32, 3, 224, 224])`.

This is how I split the dataset,

```
images = (images.numpy())
labels = (labels.numpy())
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

After splitting of the train data and test data, the new shape of X_train and X_test is `(22, 3, 224, 224)` and `(10, 3, 224, 224)`.
Now when I try to to this, problem occurs

```
# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
#fit to the trainin data
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

----> 3 classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

   537         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    538             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 539                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,
```

> ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.

I have 4 image classes and I want SVM classifier to train the model, previously I did it with CNN and Transfer Learning. I have read some post, that here I might have to reshape it. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you have 4 dimension to your input data `(batch size, channels, height, width)` you need to flatten out your images to two dimensions `(number of images, channels* height* width)`

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(22,3*224*224)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10,3*224*224)
```